# antd Table is not automatically rerendered when datasource data changes

Tags: datatable, refresh, antd, rerender

Ant Design Table is not rerendered automatically when datasource data changes.

```
<Table
                columns={columns}
                dataSource={filteredData}
                pagination={pagination}
                loading={loading}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

filteredData is changed in a method based on a custom filter which is placed outside the table.

Shouldn't the table rerender automatically when filteredData is changed?

Does anybody know how to refresh the table when filteredData is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a Table to re-render automatically, filteredData should be state.

```
onSourceChange = (something) => {
  this.setState({filteredData: something})
}
render(){
  return (
   <div>
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={this.state.filteredData}
      pagination={pagination}
      loading={loading}
      onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <button onClick={()=>onSourceChange(['a','b','c'])}>change datasource</button>
   </div>
  )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that people are still looking for answers specially with the newest version of antd.

So in Antd version 5.x table API, you could find a property call `rowKey`.

In version 4.0 table API, the property called `key` thou.

And to way to tackle the problem correctly is to set it like following:

```
<Table
   columns={columns}
   dataSource={this.state.filteredData}
   rowKey={this.state.filteredData.key}
   pagination={pagination}
   loading={loading}
   onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Note: Please consider to have a key property in your array of course. key must be unique.